# Free / Open source precise PDF to Word conversion software?

Tags: gratis, open-source, pdf, document-converter, microsoft-word

I'm trying to convert from PDF to MS Word. I've tried several online convertion, desktop programs like Nitro, ilovepdf, sejda, soda, Abby trial.

I found that with most of them, several words are joined in resultant docx document, for example `this isaquestion`, `today is Saturdayafternoon`

Comparing with the others, I get betters results with Abby software but in trial version I only can convert 100 pages and actual document has about 1000.

Do you know another good option primarily freeware/open source or that its trial period has full functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro DC could do it for a week.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try your suggestion next time. Regards